# Employer wants to film me for website videos

Tags: united-kingdom, legal, privacy, online-presence, online

(UK based)

My employer wants to interview myself and a bunch of my colleagues for a very lengthy corporate video to go on the website. It is quite a big name and there would be a lot of traffic from all over the world.

Am I right in thinking that they can't legally force me to do so? I've been there for 2 years and passed my probation long ago.

Without going into too much detail, the video would still be online for years and years even if I were to later quit the job... which I find very uncomfortable to think about.

Also, the majority of people on a similar salary to me haven't even been asked about it, so I dont see how it is fair that I have to.

There was never any mention of doing something like this at my job interview originally.

Can I also refuse an audio-only interview if they try to get me to do that instead? I'm honestly not keen on either.

Comment: Ask HR or your manager directly to see if you have the option not to be filmed for this company. They will tell you "YES" or "NO", and give you the reasons and good explanations.

Comment: As always in these situations, the key is to **decline** (their generous and amazing opportunity) not to **refuse** (a burden no sensible person would want to be part of). Just thankyou, but no thankyou. Refusing gets hackles up and leads in directions you won't like.

Comment: Have you actually just told them nicely that you don't want to participate? And if so what did they say? Before resorting to legal steps that seem the logical thing to do.

Comment: What's your job description though? Your employer doesn't own you. They just hire you to fill a particular *position*. If these demands are reasonably unrelated to the position, then it would be reasonable to refuse. I'm just talking common sense - I don't know the legality, they may depend on laws and any "fine print" in your contract - a lawyer can tell you.

Comment: Employers are being cheap. They can easily hire actors or external professionals that will do a better job than OP. If the idea is to get company specific information recorded, and then **posted on a website**, you may want to let the corporate legal team know what is happening. The mere fact that it goes on a public website means using internal staff is probably not the best idea.

Comment: @Nelson That really depends on the context. Nobody expects the Walmart cashier in the TV ad to actually work at Walmart. But if an IT company puts out a "Meet our Team" video, and it later turns out that nobody in this video actually works for the company, Reddit will be all over it.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

In order to evade the potential legal complications, I believe a more pertinent question would be:

> "How can I avoid participating in the interviews without damaging my relationship with my employer?"

This is a simple task - honesty is key, minus the obvious likelihood that you may not work with them in a few years. For me, a fairly straightforward script has always sufficed whenever I didn't want to be involved in such activities:

"Hello XYZ, I understand that you wished for me to partake in the video/photo-shoot/interviews, but to be truthful, I'm not keen on the idea of having such a broad online presence. I generally steer clear of social media, and the dissemination of my words, photos, and videos on the internet makes me uneasy. Thank you for your understanding."

It truly doesn't need to be more complex than that. If your wishes are subsequently disregarded and the tone shifts from a request to an authoritative command, that would be an appropriate occasion to pose a second question. But initially, it's best to maintain a light approach.

Comment: Good. I would add  "thank you for the honor of being asked to appear".

Comment: I agree. The problem with trying to be specific and give, or even invent(!!!), detailed justifications, is that those justifications then give the employer points to latch on to. For example, imagine you say "I am not good at public speaking" and then the employer decides to send you to an all-expenses-paid seminar on public speaking? Now, the reason you gave them for not doing the interview is gone and if you come up with another one, you will lose credibility! Keep it general, vague, but truthful.

Comment: @BasilBourque "Thank you for asking me" is good yes, but calling it an "honor" seems silly and since the OP obviously does not consider it an honor, it is also likely to come across as sarcastic.

Comment: @terdon: The OP does not consider it an honor. However, the employer might, and thus might mistake failure to acknowledge the opportunity as such for being ungrateful.

Comment: "I generally steer clear of social media" is fine, if it's true.

Comment: I would avoid a detailed explanation, as it opens you up for argumentation. A simple "I'd rather not participate for personal reasons" should be enough, at least in writing. They may ask you for details, but if so, they'll do it carefully to avoid stepping on anything legally protected.

Comment: +1 Decline politely, firmly, and with a very brief explanation that's actually true and unlikely to offend your employer. AKA the best way how to get out of any unwanted work tasks that aren't actually part of your job.

Comment: I would definitely NOT add 'thank you for the honor ...'.  You don't need anyone questioning why you wouldn't do something given you think it's such an honour.

Comment: _THERE IS NO HONOUR IN CORPORATE MARKETING VIDEOS._ Citation: Captain Worf

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's not a problem; making *untrue* excuses is the problem. If the true reason you don't want to do a video is that you don't feel confident in public speaking, training to fix that is a great opportunity that makes everyone come out ahead.

Comment: Photographs and videos fall under the purview of GDPR, so consent is necessary and cannot be coerced. Decline politely, and if they push you can decline more forcefully, start recording because then you mention GDPR and wait for the penny to drop. The recordings are in case it doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in other answers, raising your objections about public appearances on behalf of the company to whoever is organizing the interview casting should be sufficient usually. Your personal concerns are totally valid; if you do not want to appear publicly and you were not hired for it, there is nothing "logically wrong" about your objection.

I would, however, advise against bringing up certain lines of reasoning the way you have here:

> There was never any mention of doing something like this at my job interview originally.

Do point out you are hired and want to work as an [insert your job], which does not normally include public appearances. But rather do not nail it down to these public appearances not being mentioned at the interview, at least not without explaining how you view this particular task as extraordinarily different from your regular work.

Realistically, job descriptions can only outline the usual activities in the job, not every one-off happening that may or may not come up at some point in the future. Thus, generally refusing absolutely anything unless it is among the tasks mentioned during the initial interview might just make you appear as unnecessarily inflexible, and in the worst case, unwilling to expand your experience.

> Also, the majority of people on a similar salary to me haven't even been asked about it, so I dont see how it is fair that I have to.

This does not strike me as a surprise. Assuming you were hired for your skills in whichever job you do normally, not all of you will be equally suited to appear on film. By that, I do not mean you have to be the most handsome person in the world, just that you may look suitably "professional", your manner of speaking may be deemed appropriately suitable, like being able to form correct sentences without lots of uhs and ahs in between, and so on.

Also, note that this goes both ways. You say you do not want to see your video online after you have quit that job. Likewise, the company probably doesn't want to have an advertisement video online that contains someone who might become a vocal critic of the company later on (maybe you know you won't, but they don't). By offering this participation to you, they show at least in part they deem you sufficiently loyal to the company to represent it publicly.

Therefore, I'd bring up this fairness angle only if they really try pressing the point without leaving a way out.

Comment: Thank you – All good points, also I'll keep that in mind about not referencing my job interview or description and whatnot.

Comment: Every job contact I've seen contains the clause "and other duties as assigned." You can say "I'd rather not", certainly. And that may be all that's needed. You may have trouble outright refusing.

Answer (score -2):

> Am I right in thinking that they can't legally force me to do so?

In most legislations they would need you to sign a "release form" before they can publish a video or audio track. It's also possible that there is a global release already in your employment contract or part of the employee handbook. It would be useful to read on up on that. But chances are, they can't legally force you.

Regardless of  the legality, it's unlikely that they would push the issue, should you decline. Doing a video shoot is a fair bit work. It would be stupid trying to do this with someone who doesn't feel positive about that. You really want enthusiastic people in front of the camera .

However, declining will not help your career. The company is willing to invest a lot of money and effort into the videos (these things are expensive!) and is willing to make you a center piece. Most people would be excited and flattered by the proposition. You are not, so it's clear that your heart is not into your current job and/or employer. Managers do take notice of this type of thing.

> which I find very uncomfortable to think about.

Why? What exactly has you spooked here? Unless your company is doing something controversial or morally questionable, there is really no harm in being on the front page and many people would jump at the opportunity. It's only going to help your resume and future employment outlook. What specifically are you worried about?

Comment: Re your last question: some people have a legitimate personal security concern with being posted on the company's website, or simply want to have control over the use of their words, image and likeness. Or perhaps they don't want their statements about working for the company to remain on the website in the event that their feelings about the company change in the future.

Comment: @alroc Or perhaps they just don't want to. It may be hard to understand in this age of *People* magazine, paparazzi, social media, and "influencer" mania, but some people just don't want their image/voice/words blasted across the internet. No "legitimate concern" needed. Everyone has a right to privacy.

Comment: I think the conclusion "most people would jump at this, you don't, therefor you don't like your job" is incredibly shortsighted. Not to say it won't be the conclusion many managers will reach, but then they'll be shortsighted to. Some people just don't like seeing themselves on the internet.

Comment: I don't think it is true that "most people would be excited by the proposition". I think most people do not want to be famous.

Comment: "it's clear that your heart is not into your current job" you're drawing conclusions a bit quickly. There are many many valid reasons why not to want to appear in a public videos.

Comment: If they're using staff not actors, they are quite emphatically not 'spending a lot of money'. They are in fact cheapskating & the video is probably going to be truly awful - I've seen too many in-house corporate videos to hope for anything better than 'bad'. You need to *learn* to act or present. Most people shoved in front of a camera just freeze, or look like someone just out of shot is holding their bunny hostage. Few are 'just natural'. Being in front of camera is a skill, like any other. [Qualification: I work in the film/TV industry, though thankfully not often in corporate;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe there most likely is a 'release form' so that should make things easier for me to avoid it... as for the last 2 questions, some of the other commenters have pretty much summed up my views. I simply don't like my face and voice broadcast on the internet, for all I know I could end up being made a joke of in some viral meme by someone who thought it was funny (an extreme example I know). Also, due to the corporate nature of the video, it just really isnt "me" and would be very awkward for any friends of family that may happen to see it.

Comment: @user303096 - I'm fully with you on this. I like being on camera… but that's part of my job. Many people don't & shouldn't be forced into it. Additionally, if you really, really don't want to do it - it will show. Unless the film-makers are truly talent-blind [which *is* a distinct possibility] they won't get any footage they could actually use; I've seen many a corporate video done this way where every character looked like they were sitting on a broom handle, or had a gun to their head. It doesn't work for them, it doesn't work for you. The other answers cover a variety of ways to say 'no'.

Comment: *Most people would be excited and flattered by the proposition. You are not, so it's clear that your heart is not into your current job and/or employer.* I completely disagree. The fact that you want or do not want to appear in public, or be part of the ad for the company has nothing to do with your (positive) emotional attachment to said company.

Comment: _italic_Most people would be excited and flattered by the proposition. You are not, so it's clear that your heart is not into your current job and/or employer._italic_ Adding my voice to the disagree-ers. I like my job as software developer at my current company but i too would decline any public video appearence. That's not what i'm there to do and i also dislike having my image on the internet for who knows to see. Similary i do not have any social media as i view it as a big net negative to society. Don't project your own opinion onto others.

Comment: @Tetsujin It depends. If the video was supposed to be about a serious matter (opposed to, say, an ad), I'd _very_ much prefer the actual specialists participating, even with poor "acting" skills, instead of perfectly looking hired actors, speaking memorized techno-/corpobabble and not understanding a word.

Comment: @TrangOul - your call. Not really the place to discuss this, but to me an hour of employee vox pop would be unwatchable.